# Fixed point convergence of a coupled iterative vector scheme

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I need to prove the convergence of a coupled iterative scheme. The scheme results from the discretization of a problem from function space to a finite-dimensional vector space, and is as follows:

$AX = b \times\max(Y - X - a, 0)$ and
$AY = b \times\max(X + a - Y, 0)$
where $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$; $X, Y, a\in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $b$ is a real scalar.

Take the first equation $AX = b \times\max(Y - X - a, 0)$ and pin $Y$, I write $X = f(X)$. I am able to show $f$ is a contraction, and apply the Banach fixed point theorem. This I can do since I can show for $(X, d)$ to be a complete metric space, where $d$ is the $p$-norm on $R^n$; and I am able to compute the bound of the induced matrix norm for the inverse of $-A$, which is 'correctly' bounded (i.e. $X = -A^{-1}(b \times \min(X, Y-a) - b \times (Y-a))$ contracts). Similar for $AY =... $

Thus for respectively $X$, and $Y$ I am able to compute its fixed point (by iteration) given the value of the other. Therefore if I initialise $X$ and $Y$ and iterate the fixed point computations, my overall scheme must go 'somewhere'. Intuitively (and by computer) it makes sense for both $X$ and $Y$ to converge, however I can not seem to prove it.

The scheme would result in a sequence of fixed points, and contractions for both $X$, and $Y$. I opted for Theorem $1.2$ from 'Lectures On Some Fixed Point Theorems Of Functional Analysis' by F.F. Bonsall which is as follows:

Let $E$ be a complete metric space, and let $T$ and $T_n(n =1, 2, \cdots)$ be contraction mappings of $E$ into itself with the same Lipschitz constant $K < 1$, and with fixed points $u$ and $u_n$ respectively. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to ∞} T_nx = Tx$ for every $x \in E$. Then $\lim_{n\to ∞} u_n=u $.

Besides the technical details (quite a strong/restrictive Lipschitz constant condition, which might not hold in my case), I would not be able to use the result since my contractions for either $X$ or $Y$ depend on the other. Thus I would need to assume what I try to prove for "suppose that $\lim_{n\to ∞} T_nx = Tx$" to make sense.

I also thought of doing just one iteration for each fixed point search, and then switch equations. This seems to converge similarly (by computer) though I would think is harder to prove (I do not know what I have at hand after a single fixed point iteration, whereas if I continue I would have the fixed point which opens doors..?).

I feel like it is not necessarily a very hard problem, however I seem to be stuck in circle-reasoning. Is there any work on these type of problems I am unaware of? Or maybe a completely different route towards a solution?

Comment: Have you tried the usual approach to these coupled equations: piling everything into a single vector equation? If you let $\mathbf{X}=\pmatrix{X\\Y}$, $\mathbf{A} = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&A}$, $\mathbf{a} = \pmatrix{a\\0}$, and $\mathbf{J}=\pmatrix{-I & I \\ I & -I}$, then your equation becomes$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = b \max\{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{a}),0\}.$$Have you tried analysing this equation in $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ instead?

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your response! I did not yet amend the problem as such, I will try and go from here!

Comment: @TheoBendit So I tried... as I said I know my induced norm(w.r.t to the infinity norm under R^n) for my original A is bounded, in fact norm(inv(-A)) <= 1/(b+r) where b is from the problem, and r a scalar in R. Given this information, I compute for the amended problem, norm(inv(-A)) <= 1/(b+r) and norm(J) = 2. If I now try to prove contraction I get the result for the amended equation not to contract. I am not sure if this is correct however, since I would expect it to contract...

Comment: A correction on my comment above: it really should be$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = b \max\{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{a}),0\}$$instead, not that this will really help you along. It's difficult to comment without seeing your attempt in more detail, but maybe this will help. Yes, $J$, as an operator on $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$, has Lipschitz constant $2$. But, all of your iterate vectors are in the non-negative orthant (due to the $\max$ condition), and in this orthant, $J$ actually has Lipschitz constant $1$. Would this help things?

Comment: @TheoBendit I first rewrote my equation as $-AX = bmin(-J(X+a), 0)$. I then decided to write $-AX = b(min(JX, -Ja) -JX)$, finally $X = (-A)^{-1}b(min(JX, -Ja) -JX)$. I would now compute $d(T(X), T(Y))$ and show $d(T(X), T(Y)) <= qd(X, Y)$ for $q \in [0,1)$. $d(T(X), T(Y)) = ||b(-A)^{-1}(min(JX, -Ja) -min(JY, -Ja) -J(X-Y))||$. I would now use my previous result on the bound of $||(-A)^{-1}||$ which gives $||b(-A)^{-1}(min(JX, -Ja) -min(JY, -Ja) -J(X-Y))|| <= b||(-A)^{-1}||*||min(JX, -Ja) -min(JY, -Ja) -J(X-Y)|| = (b/(r+b))*||min(JX, -Ja) -min(JY, -Ja) -J(X-Y)||$. ...

Comment: @TheoBendit ... To deal with $||min(JX, -Ja) -min(JY, -Ja) -J(X-Y)||$ I decided to take $J$ out of the elementwise min-operator, thus I get $||J(min(X, -a) - min(Y, -a) - (X-Y))||$. I would now compute $||J|| = 2$ and would again use the sub-multiplicative property. Thus $(b/(r+b))∗||min(JX,−Ja)−min(JY,−Ja)−J(X−Y)||$ $<=$ $(2b/(r+b))*||min(X,-a) - min(Y, -a) - (X-Y)||$. I now argue for the elementwise min-operator to contract by definition and use this and the triangle-inequality to say $(2b/(r+b))*||min(X, -a) - min(Y, -a) - (X-Y)||$ $<=$  $(2b/(r+b))*(||X-Y|| - ||(X-Y)||)$ which collapses...

Comment: @TheoBendit I hope I am not bothering you, but do you now where I went wrong in my approach?

Comment: Hi coenhobelix, you aren't bothering me, and your request is reasonable, but at the same time, I can't say I feel like picking through the argument packed into the above comments right now (due mainly to personal reasons). I might come back to it, in a few days to a week (or possibly not), but I would suggest asking a new question with this detail included. Good luck with it.

Comment: @TheoBendit Hopefully you are well. I made the follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750999/fixed-point-convergence-of-vector-scheme   (in case you at some point are in the position to answer, however feel absolutely free to not respond at all!) All the best!